# Do I need to generate a JSON request to send data to Waze when using Road Closures (ArcGIS Solutions for Local Government)?

Tags: arcgis-local-government, waze

We are new to the Waze for Cities program. Currently, I am trying to get information regarding how to submit road closure data to Waze using [Road Closure](https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsolutions.arcgis.com%2Flocal-government%2Fhelp%2Froad-closures) solution. I read all the documentation for this solution, as well as the guidelines provided by Waze for this task. Being an Esri shop, we want to use this tool rather than Waze Map Editor since WME will not work for our workflow.

Per Esri’s documentation for this solution, in order to share our road closure data, we must create a JSON request from the feature layer. I was under the impression that deploying this tool and configuring the Organization ID, etc. will handle all these things.

Can someone elaborate on this topic?

See the following two links:

https://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/road-closures/workflows/share-waze/

https://developers.google.com/waze/data-feed/overview

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of this help topic it describes how you share your Road Closures service with Waze in such a way that it returns the features as json in the format required by Waze. You really don't need to do anything special to the service that is deployed with the Solution you just need to format the url in a specific way to send to Waze.

https://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/road-closures/workflows/share-waze/